# Can RDBMS scale on read similar to noSQL?

Tags: architecture, nosql, rdbms

After doing some research on Dynamodb, I realized their focus is on having a non-blocking write and therefore can scale the db horizontally with many machines using the consistent hashing scheme.

My question is, if my need is read heavy (let's say KV pair data, so no join) and write is light. Can I still get good scalability by using SQL likes database? Because if write is light then I don't really need the write availability Dynamodb provides. I can simply adding more slave machines to RDBMS to scale on read, although write can take a hit but assumption is I don't need to scale write so that should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a question of consistency - if you scale out, how do you manage the update process?  Because it's likely you'll have some databases out-of-sync with other ones while the update propagates, so which value a caller gets will depend on which instance they happen to talk to.  Whether or not that's "bad" for you is only something you will know.

In the scenarios I have seen, usually you have a central RDBMS and that's fine (scale-up if needed).  Replication is usually used for keeping DR instances ready.

Some DB platforms have high-availability functionality that would allow you to scale out but I would imagine it's quite specialized ($$$).

If you really want to scale out data for read-intensive purposes then a specialist caching solution of some kind might be better.  And you  can use write-through or write-behind patterns (etc) to up-date them.